# Should i signup for a worker-dyno to get delayed-jobs working on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Am a bit confused, If I have to signup for Worker-Dyno to get the delayed-jobs working. This article didn't specify any : http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job#setting_up_delayed_job

Please, help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article specify a worker on section **Running DJ Workers on Heroku/Bamboo** with the command `heroku workers 1` and on section **Running DJ Workers on Heroku/Cedar** with `heroku scale worker=1`

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need a worker to run jobs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Cedar, you can have [a worker dyno for free](http://www.heroku.com/pricing#0-1), but that means you don't get the free web dyno, which certainly [complicates](http://aegif-labo.blogspot.com/2011/10/where-to-run-your-background-jobs-for.html) things.

See the **Scaling web dynos to 0** paragraph of [the documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/billing-changes#specifics_on_changes).